# Presence or absence of leading "/" in a rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter website which has a broken link structure. The initial page loads normally. My Navbar looks like:

```
<a class="brand" href="#">myproject</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/Facts">Facts</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/about">About</a></li>
              <li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact">Contact</a></li>
              <!--<li ><a href="http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/privacy">Privacy</a></li>-->
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I've tested it locally with the following .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This appears to fix the directory structure (I assumed) by turning:

```
http://localhost/projectname/basecontroller/contact
```

into:

```
http://localhost/projectname/index.php/basecontroller/contact
```

If I change the last line in the .htacess to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

It works on my production server but not locally on my wamp

Can someone explain the significance of the leading "/"?

Comment: Do you specify the url (or the domain) as the example you've provided (hard-coded) or you use some helper function?

Comment: This is codeigniter so I am using li><?php echo anchor('basecontroller/contact', 'contact') ?></li>

Comment: If your htaccess is in `projectname` folder and you use `index.php/$1` it will work because this means `in the same folder, use index.php`. Note this is the same as `/projectname/index.php/$1` (you can use `RewriteBase`). But if you use `/index.php/$1` this means `in the ROOT folder, use index.php` so that's why it does not work (and it's even weird it works on your prod)

Comment: Can you enter that as an answer Justin?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Rahul, this works but doesn't really answer the question . - Thanks Bill